# Question about adverbial prepositional phrase in mission statement

Tags: adverbial-phrases

The company I work for is working on a mission statement for our blog. Currently, there's a debate over which of the following is correct (or *more* correct):

*To empower our customers to make well-informed decisions through honest and compelling content.*

or

*To empower our customers through honest and compelling content to make well-informed decisions.*

The main point of contention is whether the adverbial prepositional phrase "through honest and compelling content" should directly follow the verb phrase it modifies, or if it should be placed at the end of the statement because it sounds more "natural."

I've read some good and informative threads about adverbial phrases on this board, but I'm still not sure what the answer is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is Off Topic "writing advice". But my advice is to use the first version - where *what the company actually does* is contained in the final clause, giving it a bit more emphasis. Besides which ***to empower our customers*** and ***to make well-informed decisions*** represents a single coherent concept, that shouldn't be "muddied" by interposing another lengthy adverbial element.

Comment: Moving "through...content" to end suggest that the customers may be making both decisions and content. You could always put the "through" clause at the start, or use something better like "provide honest and compelling content to empower..." But yes, off-topic.

Comment: @StuartF They're not asking for an opinion if it sounds nice. They're asking an objective question about the difference in meaning (or acceptability) based on syntax choice.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the adverbial depends on different verbs and so that two different things are said following that it is found in one place rather than the other.

> To empower our customers to make well-informed decisions through honest and compelling content.

In the first sentence, the decision is made "through honest and compelling content" and so this content is specifically the means to arrive at the decisions, but it is not necessarily provided by who is offering services or goods for sale, and those latter might only be educating the customer so that he/she can discriminate between types of content.

> To empower our customers through honest and compelling content to make well-informed decisions.

In the second, the content is the means that will permit the provider   of  a service or goods to give the customer the possibility to make an informed decision, but nothing says that such content will be the means the customer will use.

If the intention is, as I believe it probably is, to provide the customer with special content from which he/she will decide, this might be preferable.

- To provide our customers with honest and compelling content that will enable them to make well-informed decisions.